# antd Dropdown: Stop Propagation of Click Trigger

Tags: antd

I'm looking for a way to `stopPropagation()` the click event of an antd [Dropdown](https://ant.design/components/dropdown/) component with a sole 'click' trigger.

Here's an example of a Dropdown where the open/close click event is propagated to the parent Collapse header, which causes the Panel to collapse/expand, which is undesired:

https://codesandbox.io/s/stop-propagation-dropdown-trigger-click-cg005

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtFrt.png)

Note that click events of the button and the menu items can be stopped from propagating in the respective event handlers.

What I'm looking for is how to do the same for the dropdown click events (click on the "⋯" part), which doesn't seem to be easily accessible.

Comment: Tried to fix the issue, no solution yet. Interesting question.

Comment: If you don't find a solution you probably need to control the open state of the dropdown yourself.

Comment: @mleister Yes, that's what I thought too. I was hoping to somehow avoid that... :)

Comment: did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Providing the `onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}` callback to the immediate child of `<Dropdown trigger={["click"]}>` should solve the issue. Tt worked for me:

```
return (
            <Dropdown trigger={["click"]} overlay={actionsMenu}>
                <div onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()} className="action-button-container">
                    <MoreOutlined />
                </div>
            </Dropdown>
        )
```

Comment: This worked a treat for me. I had an AntD Button as a child to the Dropdown and it worked there. Not sure why this hasn't been marked as the accepted answer??

Comment: this answer only makes the primary button stop propagation, which is not exactly what the question is asking.  It's about making the open/close of the menu trigger stop propagation

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using onClick Dropdown menu prop

```
<Dropdown menu={{ items: options, onClick }} trigger={['click']}>
    <Button
        type="text"
        size="small"
        onClick={event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation(); // stop propagation main button
        }}
     >
        <MoreOutlined />
     </Button>
 </Dropdown>
```

and onClick menu function :

```
    const onClick = e => {
        e.domEvent.stopPropagation(); // stop propagation menu items
        // todo
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

@shimikano, as for your particular case, you can override the buttons by using the **buttonsRender** prop from the <Dropdown.Button> component. buttonsRender is a function that receives an array with 2 ReactNode elements inside, first one is the actual button (named Dropdown in your case), and the second one is more icon which you can override with the same icon to which you have access and can provide the onClick callback and call event.stopPropagation() inside

```
buttonsRender={buttons => {
    buttons[1] = <MoreOutlined onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()} />;
    return buttons;
}}
```

Here is how the collapse header would look like:

```
const header = (
        <Space wrap>
            <Dropdown.Button
                size="small"
                trigger={["click"]}
                onClick={handleButtonClick}
                overlay={menu}
                buttonsRender={buttons => {
                    buttons[1] = <MoreOutlined onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()} />;
                    return buttons;
                }}
            >
                Dropdown
            </Dropdown.Button>
        </Space>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Asked [on github](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/45372) and got a solution back using the `buttonRender` prop:

```
buttonsRender={([left, right]) => [
        left,
        React.cloneElement(right, {
          onClick: (e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
          }
        })
      ]}
```

Full working example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-973ks9?file=/index.js